# TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined vue-resource.js:284

Tags: php, jquery, vue.js

Can anyone please help me with this error?

I have been using jQuery along with vue.js. Below is the method I am having issue with... It is called by a post request. `new_user` contains values received from the html form fields...

Values are being received nicely when I write it in console.

Problem comes when I try to use ajax method to store the data (this.$http.post()). I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
>   vue-resource.js:284

There were couple of links I went through.but i could take help from none... I might have made some silly mistakes because I used the above code from a perfectly running script. So if anyone can spot the mistake i would be grateful. Thanks... :)

Happy coding.

```
    addUser : function(new_user){
        // var instance = this;
        console.log(this)
        var new_user_input = this.new_user
        console.log(new_user_input.name)//this works fine..

         //problem comes right here
         this.$http.post("clients/" , new_user_input).then((response) => {
            alert("ok")
        },(response) => {
            alert("failed")
            this.form_errors = response.data
            // console.log("here should be the form errrors " + response.data.title)
        });
    }
```

Comment: The code looks ok, I would look the cause of your error in this.new_user data. What does it contain?

Comment: thanks for making the correction and a prompt reply. do you think using jQuery is causing this to happen since i am using $. the new_user is an object and contains data as per follows: new_user: Object address: "kathmandu" contact: "phone" dob: "1992" education: "bachelors" email: "duwaljyoti16@gmail.com" gender: "male" name: "john doe" nationality: "Nepali" phone: "45678"

Comment: Well in above code you are not using jQuery anywhere, so I don't see the reason being there... Which Vue.js and vue-resource version are you using... ?

Comment: yeah that does make sense..
i donot really understand where i messed up then..
i am using vue v1.0.24 and vue resource v1.0.3

Comment: Are you sure you want `this.new_user` instead of just `new_user` (that you're passing to the method).

Comment: actually new_user and this.new_user render same values..the issue comes at the time of using this.$http.post().

Comment: Can you post what console.log(new_user_input); logs

Comment: the new_user is an object and contains data as per follows: new_user: Object address: "kathmandu" contact: "phone" dob: "1992" education: "bachelors" email: "duwaljyoti16@gmail.com" gender: "male" name: "john doe" nationality: "Nepali" phone: "45678"

Comment: can you post this.new_user directly in post!

Comment: Also try: this.$http({"clients/", method: 'POST', data: this.new_user})

Answer (score 1):

If your using Laravel, make sure that you have in you template:

Good:

```
<script>
        window.Laravel = <?php echo json_encode([
            'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
        ]); ?>
</script>

//OR

<script>
    window.Laravel = {!! json_encode([
        'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
    ]) !!}
</script>
```

BAD:

```
<script>
        window.Laravel = '<?php echo json_encode([
            'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
        ]); ?>'
</script>

//OR

<script>
    window.Laravel = {{ json_encode([
        'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
    ]) }}
</script>
```